# ASP MVC4+JQuery validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate

I've follow the steps in the Internet to set up the validation for the password.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4+razor+jquery, but the validation seems not work.Here are my codes:

CSHTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post,new { id="resetForm"}))
{

    <ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <h5>Select the Application.</h5>
        @model PWDManagementCenter.Models.UserApplicationModels

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedUserApp, Model.userApps)
    </li>

    <li class="two">
        <h5>Input Login ID of Application</h5>
        <input name="txtLogonId"   />
    </li>

    <li class="three">
        <h5>Input the new password</h5>
        <input id="txtPwd" name="txtPwd" type="password" />
        <h6>Retype the password</h6>
        <input id="txtPwd2" name="txtPwd2" type="password" /><p />
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </li>
</ol>
}
```

JS in html:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#resetForm').validate({
            rules: {
                txtPwd: {
                    require: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 20
                },
                txtPwd2: {
                    require: true, equalTo: '#txtPwd', minlength: 6, maxlegth: 20
                }
            },
            messages: {
                txtPwd: {
                    require: "Password is required!",
                    minlength: "Password contains at least 6 characters",
                    maxlength: "Password contains at most 20 characters"
                },
                txtPwd2: {
                    equalTo: "Make sure input the same password as above"
                }
            }
        });


</script>
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(UserApplicationModels model)
        {
            string appName = model.selectedUserApp;
            string id = Request.Form["txtLogonId"];
            string newPwd = Request.Form["txtPwd"];
            string newPwd2 = Request.Form["txtPwd2"];

            ......
        }
```

When I click the submit button in debug mode, it jump to this Index function without validation.

Why? Anything I missed? Please help.

I follow this simple validation [demo](http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/)

Thanks to those who answered the question. You gave me the hits to solve the problem.

1. The script tab should end with "`</script>`" rather than " `/>` "
   So this "`<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript" />`" can't work
   but this "`<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`" works
2. After 1, I got an runtime error, saying that "jscript runtime error object doesn't support this property or method"
   This is because we include jquery twice.

After 1,2 , validation is normal.

Comment: Have you considered Unobtrusive Validation (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)? Doesn't answer your question, but makes handling client and server validation incredibly easy.

Comment: It's not what I want. Please refer to my demo link. It's simple and pure jquery. That's what I want

Comment: I understand what you want, just an FYI. UV uses jQuery and jQuery Validation, it just augments jQuery Validation so you don't have to do the manual wireup you're struggling with now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unless the code you OPed was pasted in error, your brackets/parenthesis are mis-matched. The `document.ready()` function isn't closed properly - you're missing closing `});`
2. it's `required` not "require"

   ```
   $('#resetForm').validate({
           rules: {
               txtPwd: {
                   required: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 20
               },
               txtPwd2: {
                   required: true, equalTo: '#txtPwd', minlength: 6, maxlegth: 20
               }
           },
           messages: {
               txtPwd: {
                   required: "Password is required!",
                   minlength: "Password contains at least 6 characters",
                   maxlength: "Password contains at most 20 characters"
               },
               txtPwd2: {
                   equalTo: "Make sure input the same password as above"
               }
           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be writing the jquery validation scripts manually and not relying on the unobtrusive jquery validation which is built into ASP.NET MVC. If this is the case make sure that the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` script is never referenced in your page. Also in ASP.NET MVC 4 internet template there's a `~/bundles/jqueryval` bundle containing this script, so make sure that you have never included it in your page or Layout.

All you need are the `jquery` and `jquery.validate` scripts. Also checkout your javascript console to ensure that there aren't any errors.

Comment: I only include jquery and jquery.validate, never include unobtrusive. Any idea?

Comment: Then this should work assuming you do not have some javascript errors. Did you look at the javascript console? Did you look at the network tab of your javascript debugging tool to ensure that there are no 404 errors when referencing the scripts? Did you ensure that no bundle is ever referenced in your view or in your Layout?

Comment: What do you mean by "no bundle is ever referenced in your view or in your Layout?". BTW where to see the javascript console in vs2010?

Comment: @user838204, there's no javascript console in VS. It's in your browser. For example if you are using FireFox you could use FireBug.